# How to learn OCaml efficiently?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Ok, I am a Java programmer without any functional programming knowledge.

Now I have been currently learning OCaml for 2 weeks, and I don't get even a clue about OCaml.

There are several tutorials and books suggested here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073436/ocaml-resources

but none of them seems friendly. Really, I mean it.

**None** of the tutorials or books at least gives me a `Hello World` quick start. after two weeks, I even don't know what is the `program entrance` of Ocaml (such like a `main()`).

I even have no idea of how to really write OCaml codes into a file, and somehow let OCaml compile it.

Ok, complaints are finished.

I have to learn it and do it well. So, could you please give me some suggestions of learning it? I feel OCaml is very obscurity and hard to understand. **Please enlighten my road.**

Comment: Several resources are provided on the [ocaml.org](http://ocaml.org) website. Also, a new book [Real World OCaml](http://realworldocaml.org/) will be coming out soon. Perhaps you will like it better, but I always thought Jason Hickey's book was good too. Beyond that, please pose specific questions and we'll help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you try [TryOCaml](http://try.ocamlpro.com/) website ? It can be a good start.

Answer (score 11):

I first met OCaml 4 years ago and I needed to add some little features to existing student's project at the University. I started from  [OCaml tutorial](http://mirror.ocamlcore.org/ocaml-tutorial.org/) and I understood how awesome this language is. Then I tried to write more or less big programs in OCaml and started to ask the community questions. From my experience I think you need the same thing. Pick up a favourite area of programming (web, unix tools, graphics & games, desktop applications), take a project  which is not too big or complicated for your first application. I think the OCaml community can help you to decide. You can reach them in maillist but I prefer Freenode IRC server more. And then just write some code and if something is strange ask!

Best wishes,
Kakadu

P.S. I hope OCaml will be your next big love as it has become for many of us.

Comment: I am learning from the same tutorial, just finished `Data Types and Matching`. But I still don't get `how awesome` it is. But yes, I am aiming to master it.

Comment: @Kakadu Wow just 4 and a bit parts of try ocaml and wow its just so logical and clean. Fits my brain just amazingly.

Answer (score 7):

In my personal experience I've found that a sound knowledge of the λ-calculus provides a good entrance (platform) for learning **any** functional language. But then again this is how I was introduced to functional programming, so I cannot compare it with other approaches.

You can get a good introduction to the λ-calculus from [this tutorial](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~axj/pub/papers/lambda-calculus.pdf). However it requires a little bit of mathematical thinking and might be too boring to study on your own. It would be ideal to take a module on the λ-calculus or foundations of functional programming from a university.

Note however that the λ-calculus mostly talks about the `functions` aspect only. But once you understand the functional way of computation, the rest of the language should be easy to tackle (at least that's how I felt).

Not sure if I helped or made it more confusing.

Comment: sorry Asiri, yes, you made it more confusing lol. Thanks

Comment: No worries, I think others have given you very good pointers. Wish you all the best with your endeavor!

Comment: After 3 weeks of learning, I still felt I don't understand how OCaml works and what's the key inside. I guess I will try have a look at lamda-calculus as you suggested, although I really hesitate.